# Pad rows with no data as Na in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an np array of timestamps:

```
ts = np.range(5)
In [34]: ts
Out[34]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and I have a `pandas DataFrame`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([10, 10, 10], index = [0,3,4])
In [33]: data
Out[33]: 
    0
0  10
3  10
4  10
```

The index of `data` is guaranteed to be a subset of `ts`.  I want to generate the following data frame:

```
res:
0 10
1 nan
2 nan
3 10
4 10
```

So I want the index to be `ts` and the values to be from `data`.  But for rows where timestamp doesn't exist in `data`, I want an `NaN`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [reindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) function.

For example:

```
data.reindex(index=ts)
```

Output:

```
    0
0   10
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   10
4   10
```